# change local user account name in window 10 doesn't affect the result of GetUserName API

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I change my local user account name in win10 using the [steps](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/change-local-user-account-name-in-windows-10/724d1a67-104c-49b4-bbaa-78135b317419) here

After restarting the machine, my account name did change.

But calling an API named GetUserName in visual c++ (vs2019), it always return my previous account name.

Answer (score 0):

Try `GetUserNameW`
The info is here: [Windows App Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamew)

Comment: it doesn't work either